Windows: How to auto mount all SMB shares a user has access to?
Under windows (and later Mac as well), I need the functionality where a user somehow loggs in, or types his SMB credentials into a terminal and then all shares on a (Linux) Samba server that this user has access to, are mounted.
The solution can't be that separate users on the computer have individual mount scripts. A number of users will be using the same Windows account, but with individual SMB credentials.
I thought I have had this work under Ubuntu, bot now I can't recreate it even there. (Like logging into the server in general, without specifying a share. I only see the folders in the file manager which are publicly visible.)
The net view command doesn't let me specify credentials and the net use command needs a specific share to be mounted to a specific drive-letter.
Is there maybe a way that a Batch, or Python script could fetch the accessible shares from an SMB server, by giving it user credentials and then use the list of accessible shares to individually mount them?
edit:
I found the access based share enum smb.conf parameter, which states to do pretty much that. But how do I tell the Windows browser my SMB credentials and browse the Samba Server?

What do you mean by mount? Windows keeps the credentials for successful share access per user and will use them automatically any time that this share is referenced. There is no need to officially mount the share, only to access it once.

Does assigning drive letters to each share help? https://www.troliver.com/?p=245

The scenario is that one Windows account is being used, on which different employees will be working one after the other. Each one has individual SMB credentials and needs differing groups of shares mounted, or "access" to. It doesn't help if Windows saves one set of credentials once. And the process should be easy.
